# Execute a Maven build including parameter replacement and then run app from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Java application in Eclipse which includes several property files, that have the property values as parameters which the Maven build is supposed to replace with the actual values.

However, when I run the build script with the compile goal, there's nothing created in the target folder except for the manifest.mf file, and then when I run the application, I see that the parameters were not replaced.

Here's my pom file:

```
<properties>
    <driver-version>5.1.38</driver-version>
    <jackson-core-version>2.7.0</jackson-core-version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${driver-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
<id>...</id>
<properties>...</properties>
```

What am I missing? How can I configure Eclipse to run the application with the replaced parameter values?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to replace exactly?

Comment: Values in property files, such as jdbc properties.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the following: your complete POM, where are your *properties* file(s) and how are you executing your Maven command?